# Bootstrap datetimepicker "dp.change"

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

If I use this, the change function will only fire once at opening. Selecting a different date will not trigger the change function anymore. There are 2 datetimepickers in the form. The first is to set a date and the second has to autofill the same date as the first and the time minus 3 hours.

```
$("#ed").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    var d = new Date(e.date);
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = d.getDate();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var hour = d.getHours() - 3;
    var min = d.getMinutes();
    var setter = day + '-' + month + '-' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + min;
    $('#re').data("DateTimePicker").defaultDate(setter);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this should work....

```
$("#ed").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    //Get new date value from the field on change
    var d = new Date(e.date);
    //This is for fixing the our to -3 Hours 
    //which will return to millisecond value
    d.setHours(d.getHours()-3);
    //Use .date()... please refer Bootstrap datetimepicker doc
    $('#re').data("DateTimePicker").date(d);
});
```